# I am facing issue in forwarding request parameters from one servlet to another

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to take some parameters from index.html and calling a servlet. Then I am adding some parameter to request and forwarding to second servlet. Issue is it is not identifying the added parameter and shows null .

Servlet 1

```
    package lets.use.packagehere;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


import org.apache.catalina.Context;

import lets.use.packagehere.model.Bean;
@WebServlet(urlPatterns =  "/test")

public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();

        HttpSession sessionsave = request.getSession();
        ServletContext application=getServletConfig().getServletContext();

        if(!(request.getParameterValues("list")==null))
        {
            sessionsave.setAttribute("value",request.getParameterValues("list")[0] );
            application.setAttribute("value",request.getParameterValues("list")[0] );
        }
        p.println(request.getParameter("name")+ sessionsave.getAttribute("value")+application.getAttribute("value"));                                       

        Bean test = new Bean();
        p.println(test.getA());
        request.setAttribute("check", "hi");
        RequestDispatcher check = request.getRequestDispatcher("S2");
        check.forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Servlet 2

```
package lets.use.packagehere;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns =  "/S2")
public class CHECK extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();

        p.println(request.getParameter("name")+request.getParameter("check") );
    }

}
```

index file

```
<--nocode-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="servlet">
            Name<input name="name"> 



            <select name="list" multiple="multiple">

                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                <option value="admin">Administration</option>
                <option value="biology">Biology</option>
                <option value="science">Science</option>


            </select> <br> <input type="submit">

        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Output

Hinull

I am expecting Hihi

Comment: I think the issue is that you're committing the response in the first Servlet before you forward to the second. Remove references to the PrintWriter in  that first servlet, and then try forwarding.

Comment: I commented the lines but its not working still! Issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Should use request.getAttribute("check") instead of request.getParameter("check") in your Check Class.